# Getting 'list' object has no attribute 'tolist' in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to run pyspark script. In this script i am executing sql query and creating dataframe after i am trying to change last column position into first but it is giving me error.
Can you please help me how to do this?

code:

```
if(masterjobname.endswith('ADDR_Phani')):
            df = sqlContext.sql(query)
            print("Target:  "+targetpath )
            w = (Window().orderBy("SOURCE_COLUMN_VALUE"))
            df = df.withColumn("SYSTEM_ID", dense_rank().over(w))
            cols = df.columns.tolist()
            cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]
            df = df[cols]
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay i got the answer.

`df.columns.values.tolist()` gives the list of the columns.

solution:

```
if(masterjobname.endswith('ADDR_Phani')):
            df = sqlContext.sql(query)
            print("Target:  "+targetpath )
            w = (Window().orderBy("SOURCE_COLUMN_VALUE"))
            df = df.withColumn("SYSTEM_ID", dense_rank().over(w))
            cols = df.columns.values.tolist()
            cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]
            df = df[cols]
```

Comment: Note that this error also may occur while using "tolist()" method on an already list object. So, if someone faced like this error, simply not using "tolist()" can also be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

No matter if your variable is or isn't a list:

```py
list(var)
```

You can use it as exception handling; i.e. ensure that it is indeed a list object.